# ISavedGameMetadata metadata returns Internal Error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I try to get SavedGame, but this method returns only Internal Error.

Show **LeaderbordsUI** and **AchievementsUI** works well, also I enabled Cloud saves in Cloud console.

**GPS Ver**: 0.11.01

I found some answers like I have to bild configuration:

`PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder() .EnableSavedGames() .Build();`

But there is no PlayGamesClientConfiguration in my version of GPS :(

I tried Cast Social.Active to PlayGamesPlatform - didn't work.

`ShowCloudSaveSelectUI()` - returns Internal error.

So Current realisation is:

```
// Standart UI for selecting/creating a saved game entry 
 `public void ShowCloudSaveSelectUI()
    {
        uint maxNumToDisplay = 5;
        bool allowCreateNew = false;
        bool allowDelete = true;

        ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
        savedGameClient.ShowSelectSavedGameUI("Select saved data",
            maxNumToDisplay,
            allowCreateNew,
            allowDelete,
            OnSavedGameSelectedCallback);
    }

    // Open Save file
    public void OpenSavedGame(string filename)
    {
        ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;

        if (savedGameClient != null)
        {
            savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(filename,
            DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
            ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseMostRecentlySaved,
            OpenSaveCallback);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Do I need connect Drive API?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, Here is a basic guide on [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow, hope you read through this and edit your question. And also could you share relevant part of the code for further code investigation, So that we could help you?